# Docker security check

Tags: docker

I recently run the security check on docker server and found a few warnings in the output of this script.

```
git clone https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security.git
cd docker-bench-security
sudo sh docker-bench-security.sh
```

Section 1, 2 and 4 are related to docker daemon and section 5 is about container runtime.
I guess I can ignore most of these lines, (but should I really take action about any of these?)

```
[WARN] 1.2.1 - Ensure a separate partition for containers has been created
[WARN] 1.2.3  - Ensure auditing is configured for the Docker daemon

[WARN] 2.1  - Ensure network traffic is restricted between containers on the default bridge
[WARN] 2.8  - Enable user namespace support
[WARN] 2.11  - Ensure that authorization for Docker client commands is enabled
[WARN] 2.12  - Ensure centralized and remote logging is configured
[WARN] 2.13  - Ensure live restore is Enabled
[WARN] 2.14  - Ensure Userland Proxy is Disabled
[WARN] 2.17  - Ensure containers are restricted from acquiring new privileges

[WARN] 4.1  - Ensure a user for the container has been created
[WARN]      * Running as root: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 4.5  - Ensure Content trust for Docker is Enabled
[WARN] 4.6  - Ensure that HEALTHCHECK instructions have been added to container images
[WARN]      * No Healthcheck found: [shantanuo/notebook:latest]
[WARN]      * No Healthcheck found: [elasticsearch:7.3.1]
[WARN]      * No Healthcheck found: [russmckendrick/ab:latest]
[WARN]      * No Healthcheck found: [russmckendrick/nginx-php:latest]

[WARN] 5.1  - Ensure that, if applicable, an AppArmor Profile is enabled
[WARN]      * No AppArmorProfile Found: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.2  - Ensure that, if applicable, SELinux security options are set
[WARN]      * No SecurityOptions Found: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.10  - Ensure that the memory usage for containers is limited
[WARN]      * Container running without memory restrictions: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.11  - Ensure CPU priority is set appropriately on the container
[WARN]      * Container running without CPU restrictions: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.12  - Ensure that the container's root filesystem is mounted as read only
[WARN]      * Container running with root FS mounted R/W: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.13  - Ensure that incoming container traffic is bound to a specific host interface
[WARN]      * Port being bound to wildcard IP: 0.0.0.0 in vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.14  - Ensure that the 'on-failure' container restart policy is set to '5'
[WARN]      * MaximumRetryCount is not set to 5: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.25  - Ensure that the container is restricted from acquiring additional privileges
[WARN]      * Privileges not restricted: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.26  - Ensure that container health is checked at runtime
[WARN]      * Health check not set: vigorous_galileo
[WARN] 5.28  - Ensure that the PIDs cgroup limit is used
[WARN]      * PIDs limit not set: vigorous_galileo
```

Comment: Check this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-audit-docker-host-security-with-docker-bench-for-security-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, the Section5 is required, because it depends on apps running on the containers. Since i have been running a chat system (memory consuming app), a no-sql database with replicas (which consumes more disk read write i/o), analytic-engine for reading through chats ( which consumes more cpu) and to limit un-necessary access from other networks.

So, the overall in order to isolate the containers this category 5 help a lot.
It provides the system level isolate for the containers.